# AngularJS routing issue

Tags: angularjs

Here, I want to print  'Nerve Center Dashboard' when route is '/' ,'Consumption Dashboard' for '/consumption' and same for every route in `<p>` tag. Please help

```
<html>

 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

<body ng-app="myapp">
    <p></p> /------------*text to be printed*-------------/
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li onclick="dashboardTitle('Nerve Center Dashboard')" id="nerve"><a href="#/">Nerve Center</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="dashboardTitle('Consumption Dashboard')" id="consumptionn"><a href="#consumption">Consumption Analysis</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="dashboardTitle('Fulfillment Dashboard')" id="fulfillmentt"><a href="#fulfillment">Fulfillment Analysis</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="dashboardTitle('Inventory Dashboard')" id="inventoryy"><a href="#inventory">Inventory Analysis</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class='col-xs-12 rmpm' style='height:auto;'>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
        //routing for tabs
        myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
                //      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  
                $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'nervecenter.html',
                    controller: 'nervecenterController'
                }).
                when('/fulfillment', {
                    templateUrl: 'fulfillment.html',
                    controller: 'fulfillmentController'
                }).
                when('/consumption', {
                    templateUrl: 'consumption.html',
                    controller: 'consumptionController'
                }).
                when('/inventory', {
                    templateUrl: 'inventory.html',
                    controller: 'inventoryController'
                }).otherwise({
                    templateUrl: 'nervecenter.html'
                });
            }
        ]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So what seems to be the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I cant find logic to print in <p> tag for every route

Comment: Initialise a variable to the desired value in each controller and print that. You have to declare it on $rootScope

Comment: Please show me.

Comment: Check the answer and see if there is any problem

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a global variable in angular's scope to initialize the `<p>` tag based on URL. Initialise the variable in each of the controllers with the desired value. You also have to create a main controller that will be in the scope of `<p>` tag, so that any initialization on `$rootScope` will reflect under this main controller.

**Main Controller**:

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
           myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$rootScope' function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    });
    }]);
```

**First Controller**:

```
    myApp.controller('nervecenterController', ['$scope','$rootScope' function ($scope,$rootScope) {
      $rootScope.title="Nerve Center Dashboard"
    });
    }]);
```

**Second Controller**:

```
myApp.controller('consumptionController', ['$scope','$rootScope' function ($scope,$rootScope) {
  $rootScope.title="Consumption Dashboard"
});
}]);
```

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
```

**Working Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/xmLZvHK57GpaIFsHzvvV?p=preview

Comment: My bad, I forgot to declare a main controller. Try the updated answer

Comment: same issue..Nothing is being printed. No error on console.

Comment: Please do it on plunker or something else.

Comment: Can you create a plunker with the issue. It should work with the above method.Is your routing working? Are you redirected to the correct route?

Comment: Hi @ManzerAhmad I have added a wroking plunker. Please accept answer if it was helpful :)